# What are the current staged changes?

Tags: git

I've just interactively staged a few chunks of a file, `someFile.txt`. So when I look at the current status, I see the file in both staged and unstaged areas.

How do I see which of the changes are currently staged?

Comment: This seems like something I should have just Googled, but "git what's currently staged" just brings up lots of results explaining the staging area to me, which I already know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see which changes are currently staged using `git diff --cached`.

With no arguments, `git diff` will show you *unstaged* changes in the working directory; using `git diff --cached` it will show you only changes which have been staged, but not yet committed.

Comment: Nice quick fix. ;) Thanks!

Comment: Just for reference, you can also do `git diff HEAD` which will show all changes as compared to the previous commit.  IOW, it shows both the staged and unstaged changes.